# Akka persistance custom TCK plugin , How to support non java serialization for Tagged type?

Tags: serialization, akka, ignite, akka-persistence

I am building Akka persistence plugin with Apache ignite , I have a question when it comes to event tagging , if i disable java serialization(allow-java-serialization = no) , Tagged type failed to be serialized properly as i am using Protobuf for events , is there a way to configure specific serialization for Event Tagged wrapper or it need to be handled in the plugin itself?
The GitHub for my plugin : https://github.com/Romeh/akka-persistance-ignite

The exception I get is :

[2018-11-21 21:20:48] [orderManagerSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-27] ERROR a.p.i.journal.IgniteWriteJournal - Attempted to serialize message using Java serialization while `akka.actor.allow-java-serialization` was disabled. Check WARNING logs for more details.
akka.serialization.DisabledJavaSerializer$JavaSerializationException: Attempted to serialize message using Java serialization while `akka.actor.allow-java-serialization` was disabled. Check WARNING logs for more details.
[2018-11-21 21:20:48] [orderManagerSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-11] WARN  a.s.DisabledJavaSerializer - Outgoing message attempted to use Java Serialization even though `akka.actor.allow-java-serialization = off` was set! Message type was: [class akka.persistence.journal.Tagged]

I have a sample application where this issue is happening for me where I use Protobuf for events serialization , do I need to do the same for event Tagged type ?

GitHub URL example code :
https://github.com/Romeh/spring-boot-akka-event-sourcing-starter/tree/master/spring-event-sourcing-example

In Apache ignite , it is binary serialization .

Thx a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the issue got fixed by checking the msg type if it is Tagged event or not before doing the actual event storing in the journal , something like :

```
private JournalItem convert(PersistentRepr p) {
    if (p.payload() instanceof Tagged) {
        Tagged taggedMsg = (Tagged) p.payload();
        PersistentRepr persistentReprWithoutTag = new PersistentImpl(taggedMsg.payload(), p.sequenceNr(), p.persistenceId(), p.manifest(), p.deleted(), p.sender(), p.writerUuid());
        return new JournalItem(persistentReprWithoutTag.sequenceNr(), persistentReprWithoutTag.persistenceId(), serializer.toBinary(persistentReprWithoutTag), JavaConverters.asJavaCollection(taggedMsg.tags()));
    } else {
        return new JournalItem(p.sequenceNr(), p.persistenceId(), serializer.toBinary(p), null);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your workflow diagram, Akka persistence comes first so you have to convince it to pass non-Serializable objects to Apache Ignite as is.

I guess you could either

- Specify an `akka.serialization.Serializer` implementation for Protobuf which will turn Protobuf to `Array[Byte]`
- Specify an `akka.serialization.Serializer` implementation which will leverage Apache Ignite's BinaryMarshaller.marshal(Object). Note that Apache Ignite will not be aware that BinaryObject is being stored in its caches, but treat it as `byte[]`, unless you add some kind of extra handling.

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer , i agree with you completely in your explanation , i was asking if we can define custom serializer for Tagged class rather than default Java serialization as i want to switch off Java serialization completely in Akka

Comment: I think Akka is going to turn your objects to `Array[Byte]` one way or another.